# SQL Select Command Syntax Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Hopefully this is pretty simple, but I'm having some trouble. I have a table that has multiple fields but basically the two that matter are ID and year. A single ID can exist in many years. How do I set up a select statement (Which I'm ultimately using in a join in another statement) so that I can retrieve all of the distinct IDS with no duplicates for the top year that they exist for?

If there is a set of records like this:

```
ID - Year
55 - 2000
55 - 2001
56 - 2000
56 - 2002
```

So basically I want something like this returned:

```
55 - 2001
56 - 2002
```

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Year) FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID
```

References:

- [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

  - [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
- [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

  - [MAX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx)